# How to collect a data from a csv file using a specific Id?

Tags: python

I want to Iter through all the fields in the csv file when I call for the data using the specific user ID

`for name, values in df.iteritems(): print('{name}: {value}'.format(name=name,value=values[1]))`

When I run this code its iterating through the first field then moving to the next. I want it to iter through the each cells in the field one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `iterrows` method.

If `name` and `value` are column names:

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
     print('{name}:{value}'.format(name=row[0], value=row[1]))
```

If `name` is an index and `value` is a column name:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     print('{name}:{value}'.format(name=index, value=row[0]))
```

`iteritems` method has been deprecated, and it was intended to iterate through columns, not rows.